# text selection in ipad html

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I have a div with text inside of it. I want the text to be selectable (for copy/paste) on the iPad. At the same time I want to be able to handle an onclick event.
This seems not to go well together. As soon the div is clickable it is not selectable.

Does anybody know a way around this?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>

function run() {

    // do some stuff here...
}


 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- removing this onclick makes the div selectable -->
  <div onclick="run()">
  <p>AAA aaaa aaaa aaaa<p>
  <p>bbbbb bbbb BBBBB</p>   
  <div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event handlers for iOS web interaction:

```
// Replace "document" with the element you want it to apply
// to through getElementById("anId")

document.addEventListener("touchstart", run, false);
```

This will call run() when a touch has started.

The default methods of onclick, onmousedown, etc. behave weirdly on iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad.

More [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/)